# r - How can I increase the size of the panel background in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to increase the size of the panel background in ggplot2 so that extends over the axis titles like in the following graphic:

[image: Graph of GDP]

I tried to play around with element_rect but did not succeed. Here is what I got until now.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=2001:2017, y=rnorm(17,100))
ggplot2::ggplot(data=dat, ggplot2::aes(x=x, y=y)) +
ggplot2::geom_line(size=1.5)  + 
ggplot2::theme(panel.background=ggplot2::element_rect(fill="darkgrey"), 
plot.background=ggplot2::element_rect(fill="lightgrey", color=NA)) + 
ggplot2::ggtitle("Title of the plot")
```

[image: My Version]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
# first plot
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
           geom_line(size=1.5)  + 
           theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="darkgrey"),
                 plot.background=element_rect(fill="darkgrey"))
# blank plot
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
      geom_blank() + 
      theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey"),
            line = element_blank(), 
            axis.text =  element_blank(),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))

# plot with title
p2 <- p1 + ggtitle("Title of the plot", subtitle = "this is a sub") 
# plot with figure text
p3 <- p1 + ggtitle("",subtitle = "this is a second sub") 

# final plot
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p2, p, p3,  nrow = 3, rel_heights = c(10, 80, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: I like that solution! I think I might change the cowplot::plot_grid part to the gridExtra::grid.arrange function, because the cowplot adds a narrow white line to the left side of the plot(s).